# Visible all sheets except specified two sheets

Tags: vba, worksheet

I have written some code to hide and unhide sheets by changing values in the 1st worksheet, how can I make all sheets visible except for the first 2 sheets?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("H5").Value = "ADMIN" Then
        Sheets(2).Visible = True
        Sheets(2).Activate
    Else
        Sheets(2).Visible = xlVeryHidden
    End If
    If Range("G8").Value = True And Range("H5").Value = "" Then
        Sheets(3).Visible = True 'I want to visible all sheets except first two sheets.
        Sheets(4).Visible = True
        Sheets(1).Visible = xlVeryHidden
        Sheets(2).Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Else
        Sheets(3).Visible = xlVeryHidden
        Sheets(4).Visible = xlVeryHidden
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to loop thorugh all `Sheets` in your workbook, and if your `Sheet.Index` is larger than 2, then make the sheet Visible.

See loop below :

```
Dim Sht As Worksheet

' loop through all worksheets in this workbook
For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sht.Index > 2 Then ' check if index > 2
        Sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Else
        Sht.Visible = xlVeryHidden
    End If
Next Sht
```

**Entire Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Sht As Worksheet

If Range("H5").Value = "ADMIN" Then
    Sheets(2).Visible = True
    Sheets(2).Activate
Else
    Sheets(2).Visible = xlVeryHidden
End If

If Range("G8").Value = True And Range("H5").Value = "" Then
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sht.Index > 2 Then
            Sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible

        End If
    Next Sht

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: no need of `Else Sht.Visible = xlVeryHidden` and `Else Sheets(3).Visible = xlVeryHidden` `Sheets(4).Visible = xlVeryHidden`

Comment: @Adnan i just went with your original code. i thought maybe you want to keep the other sheets visible

Answer (score 0):

edited to reflect Adnan last code

you may try this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim iSht As Long

    Sheets(2).Visible = xlVeryHidden '<--| you'll make it visible if the case (see below)
    Select Case Range("H5").Value '<--| check for H5 cell only once
        Case "ADMIN"
            Sheets(2).Visible = True
            Sheets(2).Activate
        Case ""
            If Range("G8").Value Then '<--| check for it only when H5 cell value <> "ADMIN"
                For iSht = 3 To Sheets.count '<--| loop through sheets indexes greater than 2, and avoid 'If ... Then' check
                    Sheets(iSht).Visible = True
                Next iSht
                Sheets(1).Visible = xlVeryHidden '<--| hide first sheet only once
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

which does the same things as yours but some logic improvements:

- doesn't check twice for `Range("H5").Value`
- doesn't check for `Range("G8").Value` uselessly after `Range("H5").Value` is "ADMIN"
- doesn't make the `If Sht.Index > 2 Then` check at every `For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` loop
- doesn't set `Sheets(1).Visible = xlVeryHidden` at every `For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` loop

Comment: @Adnan, sorry I don't get you: what do you mean with your last comment?

Comment: sorry I'm new here. I don't idea to write code in comments

Comment: Don't. Just write comments! What's your issue with my code?

Comment: I change this line 'If Range("G8").Value=True' and the code 'Sheets(1).Visible = xlVeryHidden' should be after this line 'Sheets(iSht).Visible = True'

Comment: Why that? Since your comparing cell G8 value to True it must be storing a boolean value hence you can directly query it by means of "If Range("G8"). Value Then"

Comment: And don't see why you should repeat 'Sheets(1).Visible = xlVeryHidden' many times inside a loop

Comment: So what are your issues if you run my code as it is?

Comment: I don't repeat this code, I just change the place. Because, at this place code forced to hide all worksheets which cause error. After visible other worksheets we can hide first worksheet without any error. I think you got my point.

Comment: see edited code: I leave `Sheets(1).Visible = xlVeryHidden ` outside ` For iSht = 3 To Sheets.count` loop but placing it after its end

Comment: Actually, I have a formula in G8 which returns True or False but it also has a IFERROR formula which return "" in case of error.

Comment: And what happens if you run the code as it is while G8 has a "" value?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Sht As Worksheet

If Range("H5").Value = "ADMIN" Then
    Sheets(2).Visible = True
    Sheets(2).Activate
Else
    Sheets(2).Visible = xlVeryHidden
End If

If Range("G8").Value = True And Range("H5").Value = "" Then
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sht.Index > 2 Then
            Sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheets(1).Visible = xlVeryHidden
'     Else
'         Sht.Visible = xlVeryHidden
        End If
    Next Sht
'Else
'    Sheets(3).Visible = xlVeryHidden
'    Sheets(4).Visible = xlVeryHidden
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, I designed a Login form in First Worksheet that gives access to other worksheets, so I makes some changes in Shai Rado's Code and convert extra code to comments now it works for me.